# VS PMC EF commands error: Unrecognized command or argument 'C#'

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget-package, package-manager-console

In Visual Studio's Package Manager Console (V 6.6.0.61), the command
`get-migrations`, and other Entity Framework commands, output:

```
Specify --help for a list of available options and commands.
Unrecognized command or argument 'C#'
```

I have successfully run this and other EF commands through the PMC within the last week. But, seemingly all of a sudden, these commands produce the above two-line output. I have installed EF V6.4.4, verified by `Get-Package` and `Get-Help about_EntityFramework`.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, not Core.

`get-migrations` in PMC usually lists the migration files that have been implemented since the seed method. I'm particularly confused because "C#" doesn't appear in the command itself...

It looks like someone [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885606/entity-framework-issue) just this question a few days ago, but the author removed it.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

--

EDIT:
Here are the packages in the codebase, as reported by `Get-Package` (with `ProjectName` column removed):

```
Id                                  Versions                                                                --------                                 -----------                                   
Antlr                               {3.5.0.2}   
bootstrap                           {4.6.0}    
EntityFramework                     {6.4.4}    
jQuery                              {3.6.0}     
jQuery.Validation                   {1.19.3}     
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                {5.2.7}  
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor              {3.2.7}   
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization   {1.1.3}    
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages           {3.2.7}   
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {3.6.0}    
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Val... {3.2.12}   
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure        {1.0.0.0}  
Modernizr                           {2.8.3}    
Newtonsoft.Json                     {13.0.1}  
popper.js                           {1.16.1}    
System.Reflection                   {4.3.0}   
WebGrease                           {1.6.0}    
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                {5.2.7}   
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor              {3.2.7}    
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages           {3.2.7}   
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {3.6.0}    
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure        {1.0.0.0} 
EntityFramework                     {6.4.4}   
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                {5.2.7}    
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor              {3.2.7}  
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages           {3.2.7}    
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {3.6.0}   
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure        {1.0.0.0}  
System.Buffers                      {4.5.1}   
Ical.Net                            {4.2.0}    
MailKit                             {3.4.3}  
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {3.6.0}   
MimeKit                             {3.4.3} 
NodaTime                            {3.0.9}   
NS.Utilities.EmailHelper            {1.0.23}   
Portable.BouncyCastle               {1.9.0}   
System.Buffers                      {4.5.1} 
System.Diagnostics.EventLog         {7.0.0}    
System.Memory                       {4.5.5}   
System.Numerics.Vectors             {4.5.0}    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.... {6.0.0}   
System.Security.Principal.Windows   {5.0.0}    
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions   {4.5.4}   
Antlr                               {3.5.0.2}  
bootstrap                           {4.6.0} 
EntityFramework                     {6.4.4}   
jQuery                              {3.6.0}  
jQuery.UI.Combined                  {1.13.1}  
jQuery.Validation                   {1.19.3} 
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                {5.2.7} 
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor              {3.2.7}
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization   {1.1.3}
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages           {3.2.7}
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {3.6.0}
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Val... {3.2.12}
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure        {1.0.0.0}
Modernizr                           {2.8.3}
Newtonsoft.Json                     {13.0.1}
popper.js                           {1.16.1}
System.Buffers                      {4.5.1}
System.Reflection                   {4.3.0}
WebGrease                           {1.6.0}
```

Comment: Does rebuilding the project help you solve this issue, if it still doesn't work, please share which nuget packages are installed in your project? Also, please check whether the default items above the Package Manager are correct?

Comment: PMC is set to the correct default project. Though, no matter the default project, PMC spits out this message. Rebuilding the project doesn't do anything, nor does restarting VS or my computer. When I try to run the project, it gets stuck on a familiar error -- I really need to fun the `update-database` EF command. Still, I'm using a version of the code that previously worked fine.
 
My coworker, who is working on a different version of the code on a different machine, got the same output in his PMC. He also gets this when working on a different project in VS that also uses EF.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall Visual Studio. Then it worked again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get around this until a fix is released and won't require a reinstall of Visual Studio.

If you run your commands in Verbose mode from the PMC e.g. **Add-Migration "Name of Amendment" --verbose**, you will see that for the --language parameter, C# is being output twice.

You can copy that string out and then remove the second C# from the language parameter, paste it back into the PMC and run it.

It will then create your migration script.  **Note**, you may need to manually add the migration script to the Migrations folder in your solution via **Add->Existing Item** and select the 3 files that make up the migration script.

To update the database, run **Update-Database --verbose**, copy out the string as above and remove the second C# and then paste back into the PMC and run.

Hopefully a permanent fix will come for this one soon.